# What to do about no-global-event-listener warning for "DOM is ready" function?

Tags: javascript

Recently I started to use the ESlint plugin `@wordpress/eslint-plugin/recommended` for developing a WP plugin.

The plugin works, but the linter is not happy with it. I rather use vanilla JS than jQuery, and usually  replace jQuery's `$.ready()` with the code below:

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => {
    if (event.target.readyState === 'complete') {
        ...
    }
});
```

ESlint says:

*Avoid using (add|remove)EventListener with globals. Use `ownerDocument` or `ownerDocument.defaultView` on a node ref instead.eslint(@wordpress/no-global-event-listener)*

I'm somewhat confused what I'm supposed to change here. This is even an example on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState#readystatechange_as_event_listener_to_insert_or_modify_the_dom_before_domcontentloaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably ignore the rule. A (very) quick search revealed [the GitHub PR](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/26810) where this rule was added, and it is only intended for use in React components (emphasis mine):

> **It's only meant for React components.** Not sure if there's a way to
> make it more specific...

Comment: Thanks, I stumbled over that before (sorry, I forgot to mention it in the question) but wasn't sure about it since the rule is in the "recommend" ruleset. Looking more into it, I guess "recommended" is not meant for non React plugins [@wordpress/eslint-plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-eslint-plugin/)

Comment: Yes a lot of the JS standards and tools for WordPress these days are focused on React development in Gutenberg by core developers, so aren’t necessarily great for unrelated plugin development by third parties, unfortunately.